# Can i connect my P-45 Digital Piano to play keys on my computer?

Tags: digital-piano

Im trying to use my piano as input for buttons on my computer:)

I connected it to my PC with a USB-A to USB-B, and downloaded some software from yamaha (https://usa.yamaha.com/support/updates/umd_win64_kbd.html)
But i have no idea what else to do cause its not regestering the keys on my computer...
Im brand new here and have no idea what im doing so any help is appreciated:)

Comment: Keys? Do you mean notes? Are you trying to record something you play on your computer (in Midi)? Are you using a Daw?

Comment: Im really a beginner at this so this all sounds greek to me... (sorry) I've seen some people connect their keyboards/digital pianos to their PC i think and they have been able to make it provide input for the pc, in the form of keys, this way they can play like games or practice on the piano. (again sorry if its obv but i really am just confused) I have the software that i sent the link to downladed but i dont really know what it is or how to use it...

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about, you don't have to excuse yourself to try something new! I think @johnbelzaguy answer is a good start. I would also suggest reading it watching a few tutorials concerning the Daw you are now using (cakewalk?) and midi input! This all can be daunting at first, but the learning on these things is quite quick!

Answer (score 4):

In a nutshell, you have downloaded a driver for your keyboard which allows your PC to recognize what you play on the keyboard. The next step is to get software which will know what to do with that information.

A good starting place finding and downloading a digital audio workstation, or DAW. There are several free ones available online which you can find with a simple search, such as “free DAW for PC”. I suggest you read reviews and find one that is not a trial version as these have very limited features and will sometimes expire after the trial is over.

DAW’s generally are capable of recording audio and MIDI. MIDI is what your keyboard uses to communicate with the computer so that is what you will be using. The DAW will be able to recognize, record and play back whatever you play into it using MIDI signals transmitted through your USB cable.

This is just scratching the surface but I think it at least gives you an idea of the basic concept of using a digital piano with a computer. There are other types of music software for instruction, etc. that you can research as you become more familiar.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! much appreciated:)
I downloaded one called cakewalk but i still cant see any results when i press the keys on my piano...

Comment: @Linus I don’t know Cakewalk but for most DAW’s you must create a MIDI or software instrument track in order to input information. If that doesn’t work search Cakewalk and Yamaha support for troubleshooting issues regarding no MIDI signal. Good luck!